# How to increase maximum connection backlog limit in windows 2008 server

Tags: windows-server-2008, tcp

I have a Windows 2008 Server. Its maximum connection backlog limit (TCP) is 200. Is there any way to increase this limit to a higher value – say 1000 or 2000?

In [this article](http://kb.globalscape.com/KnowledgebaseArticle10438.aspx) you will find description of parameters to change in the registry under this key:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AFD\Parameters

The relavant values should be these:

- EnableDynamicBacklog (DWORD)
- MinimumDynamicBacklog (DWORD)
- MaximumDynamicBacklog (DWORD)
- DynamicBacklogGrowthDelta (DWORD)

I have tried using different sets of values like

- EnableDynamicBacklog = 1
- MinimumDynamicBacklog = 250
- MaximumDynamicBacklog = 20000
- DynamicBacklogGrowthDelta = 100

and

- EnableDynamicBacklog = 1
- MinimumDynamicBacklog = 20
- MaximumDynamicBacklog = 1000
- DynamicBacklogGrowthDelta = 10

but no matter what I do I am still limited to a backlog of 200 connections. (And yes I have rebooted the server between configuration changes.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Syn Attack protection has been implemented in TCP/IP stack of Vista and later OS. 
Therefore these registry parameters are no longer relevant.

Please refer to this [technet article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nettracer/archive/2010/06/01/syn-attack-protection-on-windows-vista-windows-2008-windows-7-and-windows-2008-r2.aspx) for more information about Syn Attack protection.

Comment: I don't see how this is in any way related to the question.